# Mixing Java Config and XML Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have defined some configurations in multiple Java classes, and some basic ones in the XML. For instance the dataSource is defined in XML, and am defining a JDBCTemplate in Java `@Configuration` class.

As per the answers available online, I have to use `@importResource` to include my XML, so that I can `Autowire` the bean definitions from XML. However, this does not seem to work for me. Here are my definitions:

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.mvc"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:application.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props merge="default">
            <prop key="MinLimit">3</prop>
            <prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

1 of the Java Config classes:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath*:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class MainConfig {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

And, my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I run with this setting, I get the error
`property "dataSource" must be provided`.

When I debug it, the dataSource even after autowiring is null. I tried a bunch of online solutions but none seem to work for me.

Any idea as to how I can make Java configuration class to autowire beans defined in XML? Any other setting I may have that is working against it?

Comment: completly off-topic, but you could be interested in springboot project, it encapsulate Spring to get ride of all that crappy xml configuration

Comment: Springboot does not support WAR packaging, and is not advisable to use with JSP page display like in a website. It is more suitable for Service projects, that do not display/render web pages.

Comment: You can deploy as war with springboot, but you must be sure you set the embedded tomcat as `<scope>provided</scope>`. I didn't knew about not advisable for JSP pages. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Is the import syntax correct (note the *, and the path to the file)?

```
@ImportResource("classpath*:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
```

In the past, I've had to the following:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:com/somepackages.../mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
```

reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining